# JavaScript: How to define an error in the constructor of Class syntax to deny creating an instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, error-handling, constructor

I'm in JavaScript. I want the constructor of my class `Foo` throw an error and deny creating an instance when an user tries to create instance of `Foo` without putting argument.

```
class Foo{
  constructor(_x){

    /* I guess I need to define an error here
   
    */

    this.x = _x;
  }
}

const a = new Foo(810);// create instance
const b = new Foo(); // deny creating instance and throw the error message: "Please set an argument"
```

I tried to write

```
if(!_x) return "Please set an argument";
```

at the head of constructor, but it ignored this line and unexpectedly created an instance whose property `x` is undefined.

How can I define error to turn down creating an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [`throw` an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw):

```js
if(!_x) {
    throw new Error("No argument was passed to the constructor");
}
```